# Facebook C# SDK : BatchAsync Get all friends last statuses by one batch request

Tags: c#, facebook, batch-file, facebook-c#-sdk

How can I get all friends' last statuses in one batched request? I tried the following but it is not working:

```
FacebookClient _FacebookClient = new FacebookClient ( Settings.AccessToken );

FacebookClient.PostCompleted += new EventHandler<FacebookApiEventArgs> ( _FacebookClient_PostCompleted );

FacebookClient.BatchAsync
(
    new FacebookBatchParameter [ ]
    {
        new FacebookBatchParameter( HttpMethod.Get , "/me/friends" , new Dictionary<string , object> { { "fields" , "id , name , picture" } } ) { Data = new { name = "one-friend", omit_response_on_success = false } } ,
        new FacebookBatchParameter{ Parameters = new { ids = "{result=one-friend:$.data.0.id}" } },
        new FacebookBatchParameter("{result=one-friend:$.data.0.id}/statuses",  new Dictionary<string , object> { { "limit" , "1" } , { "data" , "0" } , { "fields" , "message" } } )
    }
);
```

Comment: What version of the sdk are you using ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can answer your question using FQL, which is on my opinion much simplier. I used FacebookWebclient, but FacebookClient should work the same way.

FacebookWebClient fb = new FacebookWebClient();

```
string query0 = "SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()"; //here you get the friends list
string query1 = "SELECT uid, message, status_id FROM status WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM #query0)"; //here you get the last statuse of each friend (max 50, or max from the last 30 days)
string query2 = "SELECT uid, name FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid FROM #query1)"; //here you get the user data (in this case the name only)

dynamic result = fb.Query(query0, query1, query2); //all results
dynamic status = result[1][1]; //results of query1
dynamic friend = result[2][1]; //results of query2

for (int i = 0; i < result[1][1].Count; i++)
{
    litFeedback.Text += "<a href=\"http://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=" + status[i].uid + "\" target=\"_blank\">" + friend[i].name + "</a> : "
        + status[i].message + "<br/>" + Environment.NewLine;
}

//if not using .net 4.0:
//var result = (IList<object>)fb.Query(query1, query2);
//var result0 = ((IDictionary<string, object>)result[0])["fql_result_set"];
//var result1 = ((IDictionary<string, object>)result[1])["fql_result_set"];
```

Note:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/status/
*"The status table is limited to the last 30 days or 50 posts, whichever is greater."*

And of course you need the **permissions** for: **friends_status**